# Problem with getting the IPHDR structure from <netinet/ip.h>

Tags: c, ip, packet-sniffers

I'm currently trying to learn how to parse packets for a project.
Currently, I've been able to place the data from the ethernet header into the structure provided by netinit:

`struct ether_header *eth_header = (struct ether_header *) data;`

This works fine and I am able to get the data from each attribute.

But when I create the structure for the IP Header and try get the length:

```
  unsigned int ipheader_length = ip_header->ihl;

  printf("The header length for IP is %d: \n", ipheader_length);
```

It doesn't seem to recognise the iphdr structure and I can't actually access any of the fields.

I've included the library:
`#include <netinet/ip.h>`

But still no luck in getting access to the struct to parse the attributes from the header.

Could anyone help me get an understanding of what is going wrong?

I have a sniff function, which sniffs the packet, I then send a pointer of the start of the packet into a function called dump, this is where I defined the eth_header as well as the ip header (I used the line struct `iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *) data + ETH_HLEN;`)

Comment: Where is `ip_header` defined? Needs a [MCVE], not three lines of out of context code.

Comment: @Shawn My bad, I accidentally left out the line where I defined the header. I have a sniff function, which sniffs the packet, I then send a pointer of the start of the packet into a function called dump, this is where I defined the eth_header as well as the ip header (I used the line ```struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *) data + ETH_HLEN;```) .

Comment: Put all relevant information (eg, some of your response to the first comment.) into you original post.  And note also the exhortation to include enough of a [mcve] so that people who are otherwise able to help, may actually help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ip_header` calculation has a problem with operator precedence. The cast of `data` will happen before the addition, with the result that you'll be reading the header from the wrong memory location.

The fix is simple, add some parentheses:

```c
iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *) (data + ETH_HLEN);
```